# Error when trying to retrieve basic user information

Tags: ios, facebook

I have successfully included the Facebook Login in my IOS app however i seem to be having some difficulty getting some of the users basic information such as name, email etc....

My current code looks like this:

```
// Ask for the required permissions
    self.loginView.readPermissions = @[@"basic_info",
                                       @"user_location",
                                       @"user_birthday",
                                       @"user_likes"];

// Fetch user data
        [FBRequestConnection
         startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                           id<FBGraphUser> user,
                                           NSError *error) {
             if (!error) {                 
                 // Display the user info
                 tempLabel.text = user.name;
             }   
         }];
```

However there is always an error (where the if statement checks for !error, its always equal to false).

Can someone help me in trying to get this please?

Thanks,
Jake

EDIT:

```
2013-08-04 15:52:03.457 Ludis[37821:c07] {
    "com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode" = 400;
    "com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey" =     {
        body =         {
            error =             {
                code = 2500;
                message = "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.";
                type = OAuthException;
            };
        };
        code = 400;
    };
}
2013-08-04 15:52:03.458 Ludis[37821:c07] The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)
```

Comment: Inspect the NSError - what is the error description?

Comment: How would i go about doing this?

Comment: There is no error which shows in the log. The problem is with the error varibales shown in the code. Its defined as NSError *error within the startForMeWithCompletionHandler method.

Comment: Obviously there's an error, otherwise you would have entered the if statement. Try NSLog@("%@",[error userInfo]); or NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);

Comment: Okay i did that and it came back with some info. I will add it into the original post as its too long for here. How do i go about using an access token then?? i have the token stored in a string, but not sure how i tell it to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't obtained the user's permission to perform the action you're attempting to perform. First call

```
openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:allowLoginUI:completionHandler:
```

on FBSession. [Here's some more information](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/authenticate/) about how to log in to Facebook from iOS

Comment: Go through Facebook's tutorial - there are no shortcuts to making this work properly.